# Difference betweeen Controller::handleAction(), Controller::handleRequest(), Controller::allowed_actions and Controller::url_handlers

Tags: controller, silverstripe

In Silverstripe there exist at least four ways to direct a Controller to the right action:

1. `Controller::handleAction()`
2. `Controller::handleRequest()`
3. `Controller::allowed_actions`
4. `Controller::url_handlers`

I understand the concept of `Controller::allowed_actions` and `Controller::handleAction()`:
I can use them to define which action is executed. Then the `url_handlers` array seems to be used to add some more rules to the Controller.

So when should I use which array/Function on my Controller? When should i use `Controller::handleRequest()` and how to use this function?  And what is the difference in using the different aproaches?

So far I read a lot about this topic but each post just mention one of the above possibilities, the methods are never compared...

Here is a list of posts i've found:

- [maetl: Undocumenting PHP: URL Handling in SilverStripe](http://maetl.net/silverstripe-url-handling)
- [Silverstripe Docs: Controller](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/controller)
- [SSBits: Controllers instead of Pages](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2011/controllers-instead-of-pages/)
- [SSBits: DataObjects as Pages Part 1](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-1-keeping-it-simple/)
- [SSBits: DataObjects as Pages Part 2](http://www.ssbits.com/tutorials/2010/dataobjects-as-pages-part-2-using-model-admin-and-url-segments-to-create-a-product-catalogue/)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way of making a controller action is with allowed_actions and a corresponding method:

```
static $allowed_actions = array(
    'myaction'
);

function myaction() {
}
```

url_handlers lets you define more URL patterns, and lets you delegate control to another RequestHandler object such as a Form or FormField.  This is how the URL handling of GridField detail forms, etc, are handled.

You shouldn't really need to override handleRequest() or handleAction()

- handleRequest() is the function that parses url_handlers
- handleAction() calls methods such as 'myaction' in the example above

Hope this clears things up a bit.